# What is CHUD Remover? (Came with Xcode on OS X)

Tags: macos

I accidentally stumbled across an application called CHUD Remover that claims to remove CHUD files. It lives in /Developer/Applications/Performance Tools/CHUD.

What is CHUD and why would I want to remove CHUD files from my system?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CHUD Tools are a set of profiling and performance tools for use in applications development on the Mac.  The package includes a lot of things, such as DTrace, OpenGL Profiler, and Instruments.  Shark in particular is a favorite tool of mine; it's a spectacular profiler with a great interface.

Answer (score 9):

The other two told you what CHUD is.  The reason you would want to remove it?  To install a newer version, of course!

If you ever plan on doing performance optimization, Shark is a wonderful tool.  So don't remove it =)

Answer (score 3):

CHUD stands for `Computer Hardware Understanding Developer` Tools.

Comment: These are generally profiling / hardware performance measuring tools.

Answer (score 0):

CHUD can also cause a kernel panic and prevent the Mac from booting properly:

[com.apple.iokit.CHUDKernLib Kernel Panic Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081784/com-apple-iokit-chudkernlib-kernel-panic-fix)

Answer (score -5):

It will remove anything that slow down your computer.