# com.apple.iokit.CHUDKernLib Kernel Panic Fix

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

com.apple.iokit.CHUDKernLib seems to be causing the panic. The panic occurs everytime I boot. I can only boot in safe mode. Help! 
I have done the uninstall command for Xcode 3.2 but it didn't uninstall. Its something to do with a CHUD kext apparently. Im currently on holiday so it isnt possible to take it to the Apple store.
Its a 2012 15 MBP with Mountain lion installed.

Comment: An emergency troubleshooting/fix session over the internet via a programmers Q&A website seems unlikely.

Comment: K. Just thought here would be the place to get support from developers  who have had the same issue....

Comment: Kind of more of a superuser question, except for the nature of the package in question, but it sure saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fixed!
First of all I just want to say, anything that may happen to your machine in the process of this repair tutorial is not my responsibility.
Now we have that cleared up lets get to the tutorial! 
Ok. Lets begin on why installing Xcode 3.2.5 will cause a kernel panic at boot. Xcode installs multiple components like CHUD kexts and all sorts of other kexts to enable system more system communication (from what I can make out) so things like iPhone Simulator run properly. But these kexts (as far as I know) are 32 Bit. How do I know this?
Well they work on Lion which has 32 bit and 64 bit kernels which allows Xcode 3.2.5 to work on Lion.

Now we have that wrapped up lets get started!
1. First of all before doing anything try booting into the recovery partition on your Mac and using Disk Utility to repair permissions by holding down alt and booting into Recovery. Failing that, follow the steps below.

1. Dont worry your data is safe. Reboot your Mac and hold the shift key after the chime sound.
2. Now you should be in safe mode. Login and download [this](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/Apple-CHUD-Tools.shtml) file. What does this do? Removes all the CHUD components Xcode 3.2.5 installs which causes a kernel panic.
3. Once you have it downloaded, double click the dmg file and then you should see a folder named Utilities, click that and double click CHUD Remover and let it do its stuff.
4. In a few seconds it will notify you that it has finished doing what it does best, removing CHUD.
5. At this point you can reboot to see that your kernel panic has changed to something about AppleProfileFamily. This is another Xcode installed Kext which messes up your install. To remove it and fix the issue launch Terminal and type in this command (If something goes wrong past this point I do not hold any responsibility for anything that goes wrong) 
   sudo rm /System/Library/Extensions/AppleProfileFamily.kext
6. Type in your password and press enter.
7. Now you can reboot into a working Mountain Lion install!

Comment: Gosh! You're really helpful. I bet this answers of yours could get upvote million times! Now I can work in peace ;)

Comment: My pleasure! I was freaking the hell out when it happened I tell you now! To be honest the only reason I figured it out is because im very used to hackintoshes and reading kernel panics because of them, so thank god for Hackintosh! So I thought id share this with people who got into the mess I did. Im really glad I could help someone :)

Comment: I _am_ panic when got that Kernel Panic. Because I currently work for an hourly job for a client at that night it happens. But thanks to this article of yours, in the morning I can get Macmini up and running again. Once again, thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks. Really this problem stopped my 2 days work... i just followed your instruction to solve this issue.. once again thanks..

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, you can completely avoid this issue by not installing "System tools" in the XCode 3.

Answer (score 1):

The *this file* linked to in the accepted answer by James Heald currently links to a softpedia.com page whose *download* links seem to no longer work.  There are also a lot of links to try and get you to download MacKeeper :))

Instead, after starting in Safe Mode (shift key down), I removed the following four files which the Xcode 3 installer apparently installed, from `/System/Library/Extensions`:

`AppleProfileFamily.kext`
`CHUDProf.kext`
`CHUDKernLib.kext`
`CHUDUtils.kext`

Then I restarted normally, and I seem to be back in business.  (The reason I fingered these four files is because the kernel panic report said it occurred while loading one of them, and the other three had exactly the same date modified, in year 2010, and these were by far the oldest files in `/System/Library/Extensions`.)